# eclipse xml editor show scrolling screen graphical layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-layout

In a previous Eclipse version there was a button at the top right of the XML editor graphical layout screen that basically expanded the screen so you could see the object that were off the viewable screen.

Like if you more objects (like TextView, Button etc) so you add a ScrollView. In the code you place the other objects but there is no way to see them, graphically.

I updated everything in Eclipse a few days ago and this button seems to have disappeared.

Does anyone know how to do this or is this functionality gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest version, that toggle button is gone, and instead the mode it used to control is automatically entered when the root view is a ScrollView.

HOWEVER, there was a bug in the code which meant that the actual measurements (which the expansion-mode relies on) were wrong. It's been fixed but not yet integrated.

-- Tor